# How to control a while loop iteration in a class from a while loop outside it

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, while-loop, video-streaming, video-capture

I am trying to read frames of a video leveraging a multithreading class. So, there is a while loop inside the class, which keeps reading the video. And there is a while loop in the main, which accesses the frames from the variables of that class, but what I found is, the outer while has no control over the inner while. It is just grabbing the current running frame from the inner while.

To experiment, I put a sleep and saw the loss of frames. I do not want that, I want the outer loop to get each and every frame (zero frame drop) whatever time the outer loop takes to do other operations in each iteration, while doing so, I still want to leverage multithreading.

The code:

```
from threading import Thread
import cv2, time
import numpy as np


class VideoStreamWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        # Start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        self.status = ''
        self.frame = ''
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.thread.start()
        # self.count = 0


    def update(self):
        # Read the next frame from the stream in a different thread
        while True:
            if self.capture.isOpened():
                self.status, self.image = self.capture.read()
                self.frame = cv2.resize(self.image, (640, 480))
                # self.count += 1
            time.sleep(.01)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    path2save_results = r'D:\test_frames\multithreaded_lower\multithreaded_lower_'
    # With Multithreading enabled
    video_stream_widget1 = VideoStreamWidget(src=r'C:\Users\aa\Documents\Videos\ch6.asf')
    video_stream_widget2 = VideoStreamWidget(src=r'C:\Users\aa\Documents\Videos\ch4.asf')
    c1 = 0
    c2 = 0
    while True:
        # try:
        # start_time = time.time()

        # Added this sleep to clearly make out that interim frames are dropping out
        time.sleep(10)
        vflag, image_np = video_stream_widget1.status, video_stream_widget1.image
        if vflag:
            # new_image = cv2.resize(image_np, (640, 480))
            new_image = cv2.resize(image_np, (64, 48))
            cv2.imwrite(path2save_results + str(c1) + '.jpg', new_image)
            c1 += 1
            cv2.imshow('Lower', new_image)
            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        print('C1 is: ', c1)
```

How to go about it?

Note: I have multiple (2) videos to run in parallel, as of now I'm doing on static videos stored in hard drive, but in the longer run they'd be fed in from two cameras located separately to capture the same object from different angles. I'll be processing one's feed, based on some object detection through the other one's feed, so one shouldn't go faster than the other.

Comment: Put the frames read from one thread into a synchronized [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), get the frames from the queue on other `n` threads to process them.

Comment: Not fully aware of the concept. Can you share a code snippet on the same, so that I can implement?

Comment: Search for producer/consumer pattern. Ex: https://techmonger.github.io/55/producer-consumer-python/

Comment: I just tried implementing it, q.put(self.status, self.frame), but when doing q.get(), it is receiving only the status and missing out the frames. Why is that so? To test further, I tried sending two variables in the queue and could receive the values intact on the receiving side. Is this happening because my frames are ndarrays and due to the complex shape of data its getting garbled?

Comment: On the other hand, when I did this: q = queue.Queue(); z = queue.Queue(); self.frame = cv2.resize(self.image, (640, 480)); q.put(self.status); z.put(self.frame). Then the ndarray is properly being received on the z.get side. Do I then have to receive the two information in two separate queues? If so, will I not lose out on the synchronicity of the status number vs the frame number?

Comment: Use a data structure that holds all the information for each frame and store it in a single queue.

Comment: When I use the queue data structure, since the original frames are quite big in size I am getting the "Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)" error, which seems to be a memory error. But I cannot afford resizing the frames as my downstream is highly dependent on the given frame size (downsizing the frames make the code work, that's tested too). Is there a way to efficiently solve this?